Establishing a VPN connection between 2 PCs behind CGNAT through a cloud server
I have 3 devices in different countries. I want to establish an OpenVPN server on my machine and a client on the other 2 machines and route all their traffic through my network. The problem is that all three machines are behind a CGNAT, so none can be accessed directly via the Internet.
I read that we could use a cloud server like a free-tier Amazon EC2 instance and create a reverse SSH tunnel through that server.
I still want to route the traffic of all the devices through my network so is it possible to have the EC2 instance as a centralized server and establish a VPN connection between my machine and the other machine through this centralized server such that it simply reroutes the traffic coming from the other machine through mine?

Does it have to be OpenVPN? there's a few services like tailscale that'd do it for you

Will tailscale forward all the traffic from one machine to the other machine via the server? I'm not very familiar with it.

Its supposed to - basically uses their server to 'broker' the connection then its point to point. There's other services that do that sort of mesh networking too.
